# make changes in main page after login with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have already made registration and login pages for my web page. The question is that I want to display the name and the image of the user after login, in other words, I want to make some changes in my main page after login. 
So this is my code:
**lib.php**

```
 function checkUser($username,$password){
   include "connection.php";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'") or die("No result".mysqli_error());

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $logic = false;

    if (($row['username'] == $username) && ($row['password'] == $password)) {
        echo "Login is successfull. Welcome <b>".$row['username']."</b>";
        $logic = true;
    }
    else{
        echo "Failed to login. Username or password is incorrect. Try again.";
    }
    return $logic;  
}
function logIn($username, $password){
    include ("connection.php");
    $_SESSION["loggedInUser"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["loggedInTime"] = time();
}
```

**action.php**

```
<?php       
  include "lib.php";

  if(checkUser($username,$password)){
    logIn($username, $password);
    header("Location: index_en.php");//goes to my main page
?>
    <li><a href="#">Hello, <?php echo $username; ?></a></li>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log("successfull");
      $(".nav_header").remove();//I tried to change my index_en.php page, but no changes appear there
    </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: on successful login your redirecting your user to `index_en.php`, redirecting using `header()` will stop the execution for the rest line of code and redirect you, So your "Hello $username" will never show up, console.log() will never print to log.

Comment: What's the problem then, After a successfully login.. just fetch user details(username/Profile image) & keep in a SESSION. Then use it whenever u need those.

Comment: If you want the info to be read on another page that includes or requires `lib.php` then you would have to write to `lib.php` page. It won't automatically carry across, just because you changed some variables, if that's what you're wondering. Also, there is a lot more to login than meets the eye. Keep brute force attacks in mind. You should start by learning AJAX, really. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood the question, so I think your code might be like this,

**action.php**

```
<?php       
  include "lib.php";

  if(checkUser($username,$password)){
    logIn($username, $password);
    header("Location: index_en.php");//goes to my main page
?>
    <li><a href="#">Hello, <?php echo $username; ?></a></li>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log("successfull");
      $(".nav_header").remove();//I tried to change my index_en.php page, but no changes appear there
    </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

As, you want some change in Index_en.php(Home Page) when user is already logged in, your page should contain,
**index_en.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   echo "Hello, ".$_SESSION['username'];
}
?>
```

Comment: The `checkUser($username,$password)` and `logIn($username, $password)` functions work correctcly. I just didn't write the whole code there. The problem is to make changes inside the main page.

Comment: Why there's `header()` in action.php?

Comment: `header("Location: index_en.php");` redirects the page to index_en.php

Comment: So keep in mind that all the lines after `header()` will not be executed.

Comment: After commenting `header()`, the Hello message that I have written, appears on the white page not inside the index_en.php

Comment: because the line `<li><a href="#">Hello, <?php echo $username; ?></a></li>` is in **action.php**, not in **index_en.php**.

Comment: I don't know if it is correct, but I removed the code of action.php to index_en.php and it worked. Your advice helped.

Comment: @Ani If my answer helped, Mark it as Correct, so that users with same problem may have solution.